# if input = list[n]: How would I set this up?

Tags: python, list, if-statement, printing

I always get a bad input on the line but I'm not sure how to fix it.
sorry if it's not formatted correctly.

This is on python 2.6

```
videoGames = ["Fortnite", "Minecraft", "Roblox", "2048", "Mario Cart"]
favGame = raw_input("What is your favorite video game?")
if favGame == videoGames[1]
    print("Hi.")
print("Really?! We both enjoy playing") #add the input that matches with the list
```

If the user input matches one of the items in the list, then it will print "really?! We both enjoy playing (game)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing a colon on this line:

```
if favGame == videoGames[1]
```

It should be

```
if favGame == videoGames[1]:
```

To print the game:

```
if favGame in videoGames:
    print("Really?! We both enjoy playing", favGame)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked but now the print statement isn't printing anything <br/>videoGames = ["Fortnite", "Minecraft", "Roblox", "2048", "Mario Cart"]
<br/>favGame = raw_input("What is your favorite video game?")
<br/>if videoGames == favGame:
 <br/>print("Really?! We both enjoy playing", favGame)


<br/>print("Here are my top 5 video games.")
<br/>for n in range (0, len(videoGames)):
 <br/>print(str(n + 1) + ". " + videoGames[n])

Comment: @coolsocks As described in my answer, change `if videoGames == favGame:` to `if favGame in videoGames:`

Comment: @coolsocks No problem. BTW, welcome to StackOverflow! Please consider accepting this answer for future viewers. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers